# Deepdream python script not showing images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, caffe, deep-dream

I have followed the guide at [Link](https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb) up until the

```
_=deepdream(net, img)
```

step. Now it runs without errors but it doesn't show the images. This is the output:

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
0 0 inception_4c/output (210, 373, 3)
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
0 1 inception_4c/output (210, 373, 3)
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
0 2 inception_4c/output (210, 373, 3)
```

It continues with similar output.

I can show a file with this code:

```
im = PIL.Image.open('sky1024px.jpg')
im.show()
```

But it doesn't work with the code that the guide provides. Only thing it seems strange is that f (StringIO) contains "garbage" when I print it using f.getvalue().

Any insight on why is it not showing the images?

**EDIT:**
If I change the line (in showarray method)

```
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
```

to

```
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save('/home/jose/Downloads/deepdream/test', fmt)
```

It doesn't show the image but at least it is saving it in the specified folder.

**EDIT 2:**
Changing the line

```
display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

with

```
im = PIL.Image.open('/home/jose/Downloads/deepdream/test')
```

shows the image. Now the problem is that I can't close it so it shows one on top of the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line

```
display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

with

```
im = PIL.Image.open('/home/jose/Downloads/deepdream/test')
```

shows the image. Now the problem is that I can't close it so it shows one on top of the others.